# Store the longtitude and the latitude of a placemark into array

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

So I'm working on a webpage using the Google Earth API where a shuttle moves around the town and picks up passengers. PASSENGERS is a predefined array of objects and is a separate javascript file due to the length. Here is my code for the function `populate` which populates the 3D map with placemarks:

```
function populate()
{
// mark houses
for (var house in HOUSES)
{
    // plant house on map
    new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: "https://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/home.png",
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(HOUSES[house].lat, HOUSES[house].lng),
        title: house
    });
}

// get current URL, sans any filename
var url = window.location.href.substring(0, (window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")) + 1);

// scatter passengers
for (var i = 0; i < PASSENGERS.length; i++)
{
    // pick a random building
    var building = BUILDINGS[Math.floor(Math.random() * BUILDINGS.length)];

    // prepare placemark
    var placemark = earth.createPlacemark("");
    placemark.setName(PASSENGERS[i].name + " to " + PASSENGERS[i].house);

    // prepare icon
    var icon = earth.createIcon("");
    icon.setHref(url + "/img/" + PASSENGERS[i].username + ".jpg");

    // prepare style
    var style = earth.createStyle("");
    style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon);
    style.getIconStyle().setScale(4.0);

    // prepare stylemap
    var styleMap = earth.createStyleMap("");
    styleMap.setNormalStyle(style);
    styleMap.setHighlightStyle(style);

    // associate stylemap with placemark
    placemark.setStyleSelector(styleMap);

    // prepare point
    var point = earth.createPoint("");
    point.setAltitudeMode(earth.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
    point.setLatitude(building.lat);
    point.setLongitude(building.lng);
    point.setAltitude(0.0);

    // associate placemark with point
    placemark.setGeometry(point);

    // add placemark to Earth
    earth.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);

    // add marker to map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/man.png",
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(building.lat, building.lng),
        title: PASSENGERS[i].name + " at " + building.name
    });

    //remember passenger's placemark and marker for pick-up's sake
    PASSENGERS[i].lat = placemark.getGeometry.getLatitude();
    PASSENGERS[i].lng = placemark.getGeometry.getLongtitude();
}
}
```

However, when I load my page I get the following error from the console: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` regarding the two last lines of code: 
`PASSENGERS[i].lat = placemark.getGeometry.getLatitude();
 PASSENGERS[i].lng = placemark.getGeometry.getLongtitude()`

Any ideas how I can correctly get the lat and lng? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried placing `()` to `getGeometry` like `placemark.getGeometry().getLatitude();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said `getGeometry` is a method and needs brackets `()` to be executed.

Also looking at your code you can just use `building.lat` and `building.lng` - as these are the properties used to set the placemark's geometry in the first place.

Really it is pointless calling more methods, getGeometry().getLatitude(), to get a value you already have.

The person is at the building, no?

e.g.

```
PASSENGERS[i].lat = building.lat;
PASSENGERS[i].lng = building.lng;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is much more simple. Still wondering though ehat was wrong with that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try

PASSENGERS[i].lat = placemark.getGeometry().getLatitude();

PASSENGERS[i].lng = placemark.getGeometry().getLongtitude();

Comment: Oh it was pretty stupid forgetting those! But still the same error appears.
One more thing though... In the PASSENGERS js file there are no "lat" and "lng" keys. I'm assuming they are automatically added to each object by those two lines. Or am I wrong? Perhaps the problem is located there.